# Accessing stored images in Webpages

Tags: jsp

I am allow users to upload images on my website , these images get stored in a folder on my Desktop.
Now when i am trying to display these images on the Jsp page it is not displaying , i am using the absolute path but no use...

Someone guide please

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up two things: a way to *upload* images, and a way to *download* images. When your HTML page contains an `<img>` tag, the browser is instructed to do a HTTP GET and retrieve the content named by the URL.

Based on your question, I guess the upload part is not a problem. The only thing I suggest is not using your desktop to save images, but instead use a dedicated directory (this will be useful to protect private files as well as backing-up users' content).

Then you have to make your directory accessible from a HTTP server. You have different options here, let me name two:

1. A specialized servlet (since you are using JSP, this mean that a Java runtime is available) to be mapped to, for example `/img/{id}`, whose purpose is reading the image from the filesystem and writing its bytes to its output stream
2. Deploy a separate HTTP server (like Apache, Lighttpd, NGinX) specifically to deliver your static content, and write your URL's accordingly (for example the host will be `cdn.example.com`)

Comment: Yes i have setup a directory in the desktop and i am uploading the Image files there...

Comment: What's the problem with the two options I proposed?